# Barcode Scanners compatible with Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, hardware, peripherals

I would like to buy a barcode scanner to use with Pi, so which one will be compatible with Pi..?? Something around $50 would be great, like the Barcode Scanners we use at POS (Point of Sale), preferably an auto scan Barcode scanner with a USB type.

How will we know which type is compatible with Pi..?

[A barcode scanner like this for Pi be suitable?](http://www.amazon.in/iBall-Barcode-LS-202A-Sensing-Scanner/dp/B00KTYJ4V8/ref=pd_cp_e_1)

Comment: You going to have to look for scanners that support Linux. But like Joan answered, a barcode scanner is just a HID (human input device) and usually gets picked up like a PS2/USB keyboard. It just spits out text from the barcode.

Comment: Did you buy your barcode scanner finally?

Answer (score 2):

We have been using the [Honeywell 1900 barcode scanner](https://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-barcode-scanner&cat=HSM&pid=1900) without problem with Raspberry Pi 3B. Also was tested with Raspberry Pi B without issues.

> **note:** for RPi B model is necessary use a USB hub powered for connect the scanner. The RPi 3B support the scanner connected directly to own USB ports without problems.

Now we want start to try the [Barcode Reader/Scanner Module - CCD Camera - USB Interface](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1203) which look more cheap and flexible for our application but we must see if satisfy our requirements.

Comment: Have you tried mentioned barcode scanner? this from Adafruit site? It works? what libraries to install?

Comment: nop, really I didn't try it yet. Only the Honeywell 1900 model

Answer (score 1):

Boot your Pi.

Plug your scanner into a Pi USB port.

On the Pi go to a text window.  Make sure the text window has keyboard focus.

Scan an item.

If text appears in the text window it is compatible with the Pi.

Comment: @joan....what I was looking for was to buy a barcode scanner to use with Pi, I just edited my question now....thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Ron4326 did you find a barcode scanner that works? Do you have a product link or a product model that you tested like this and it works, and you can share? Thanks

Comment: @Radu, due to some other concerns and issues, I had to discontinue this work, so I never tested it by myself. But like what ppumkin said, anything that is compatible with Linux should work on Pi unless it has some other compatibility issues like the power rating or some other problems, or use trial and error like what joan has suggested

Comment: I ended up successfully using this one: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00406YZGK